# git checkout v0.16.3 gives error

Tags: bitcoin-core, installation

Trying to update my bitcoin core installation on raspberry pi with git checkout and it's giving the error "error: pathspec 'v0.16.3' did not match any file(s) known to git." Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

That error likely means that you have not done a `git pull` or `git fetch`. Those are required so that you can pull down the latest source code and tags so you can then do `git checkout`.

Comment: I've done git fetch as below (refers to https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin):
"git fetch origin master"
"git checkout v0.16.3"
after which I get the error